# Present Perfect vs Past Simple. Which one is correct?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect

I was watching a movie yesterday and came across a dialogue:

"What is this?"

"It's the technology I developed"

Is the word "developed" here used in the right tense? Shouldn't it be put in Present Perfect? And why if it should.

Comment: Probably, it's a reduced relative clause, but I'm not sure. I'm also a learner. Imo, *It's the technology (that was) developed by me* the *developed by me* part perhaps reverted into *I developed*. However, I might be wrong. It's also ok to say *It's the technology that I have developed*

Comment: This is specifically an American usage of simple past. In the United States, it's common to use simple past for the function of "past event with present result". Elsewhere around the world, we strongly prefer or even require present perfect. This is one of those situations.

Comment: @gotube: "specifically an American usage" is putting it a bit strong. It's true that the preference for Simple Past is stronger in AmE, but as [this NGram shows,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=method+I+developed%2Cmethod+I+have+developed%2Cmethod+I%27ve+developed&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=10) the two different verb forms are now about equally common in BrE (and that's *written* BrE inclusive of citing historical texts; I'm sure current *spoken* BrE will already significantly favour Simple Past, same as AmE).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That Ngram doesn't indicate what the function of the simple past was in each case. My assertion is about the function: "*past event with present result*". Many/most of the simple past hits could be about a finished past time, like "*a method I developed **last year***". That said, my assertion is based on what my Linguistics profs told me in the early 2000s, so it may be out of date now.

Comment: @gotube: I don't think it really matters "what the function of the simple past was in each case". [This is an NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+developed%2C%28I+have+developed%29%2B%28I%27ve+developed%29&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20developed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28I%20have%20developed%29%20%2B%20%28I%20%27ve%20developed%29%3B%2Cc0) comparing Simple Past / Present Perfect in BrE, and it's easy to switch the corpus to AmE. *On average,* the words used are broadly comparable, and the real-world contexts *must* be much the same.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Notice that Americans use the simple past way more than present perfect, but Brits do not (yet). That difference literally means Americans use simple past for certain functions where the rest of the world uses present perfect, which is what I said.

Comment: @gotube: I still think you're presenting the US/UK split here as far more extreme than it actually *is*. If I go for the slightly more "formal" context of developing *arguments*, and include examples with the (again, *on average* more formal) relativiser ***that***, the link is too long for a comment, but if you cut & paste **(argument I developed)+(argument that I developed),(argument I have developed)+(argument that I have developed)** into NGrams, then even when restricting results to just AmE, Present Perfect is nearly twice as common as Simple Past. But this one could run and run...

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think we're doing a good job of narrowing the scope of my assertion, but I still feel it's worth something, so I'm going to leave it. Thanks for the constructive criticism

Comment: @gotube: For the avoidance of doubt, I was never claiming that there isn't a statistically significant US/UK usage split here. But *in practice*, I think almost no British Anglophone would notice anything remotely unusual if one of his compatriots used the "typically American" verb form (and I kinda doubt that many Americans would think anything of it if they heard another American using the "typically British" form). I just wouldn't want to encourage learners to think Brits and Americans are *that* far apart in their usages (which are probably rapidly converging post-Internet anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers True. Here in Canada, we usually don't blink an eye when we hear the "American" form, though occasionally it registers as a 2 out of 10 on the Odd-o-Meter. No American has ever commented on my choice of present perfect, though my students have commented on American usage of simple past, like this OP has (or "did").

Comment: "Odd-o-Meter"? I like it! :) Have to be grateful to Americans for setting that one up, since over on this side of the pond we still have ***milometers***.

Comment: I wish to heck people would stop this BrE/AmE thing. In this particular question, **I developed** versus **I have developed** has to do with **what the speaker wants to say** and not with anything else. Any BrE or AmE or Canadian speaker might say either of these depending on their particular situation. "I have developed" signal that the thing is in the past. "I developed" signals the developing is finished.

Comment: Looking at other verbs, [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=book+I+wrote%2Cbook+I+have+written%2C+book+i%27ve+written&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10) shows a strong preference for "book I wrote" over "book I have written" even in British English. Although I wonder if there's a difference in usage depending how exactly it's used, or if you're getting false matches like "Have you read the book? I wrote it for you."

Answer (score 0):

Either is fine.

In American English, you would most often say:

> It's the technology I developed.

I believe that non-American English favors this version:

> It's the technology I've developed.

Comment: This is not about AmE versus BrE. It is really disheartening to read over and over and over in these English forums this myth.

Comment: @Lambie: Then what is it about?

Comment: The use of the present perfect versus simple past has zero to do with whether it is BrE or AmE. There are tons of answers on this site about that.

Answer (score 0):

**What do you want to say?**

That you did something in the past *relative to the present* without saying when?

OK: So, you'd say:

- This is the technology **I've developed**.

Or do you want to say that the development is finished?

OK: So, you say:

- This is the technology I developed and now I'm developing a different one.

This is the bare bones of the difference between simple past and present perfect.

All these opinions re BrE and AmE and who uses what is not provable.

American English speaker:
You take that weather data, which is temperature and relative humidity, then you cross that with the weather data from the satellites today, you feed that into our program that we have developed over the last several years, and then that will tell you how tall, how wide the tower needs to be at that location, how much water you need to interject at right intervals and how much electricity, how many kilowatts per hour it will make 24/7/365.
[Wall Street Journal](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/wall-street-transcript-interview-ronald-162800596.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAANO0H9aVo9QV2YMD4yBRF0x1fRiW5xVr6hharcdwO6ytCmO43TEoo9NTus_Bu6fPZm7HUv11WZdVQ9Aoz9qu9EOS4GqNtJ8QbcI1QvAmHQojsfLAfOA2ug5Gcz0DRPxk1c3t8z9xUCD8itM0YIctJbRu6CSs0J2l3wo6c19HctOF)

American CEO, Steve Jobs

In a remarkable turn of events, Apple bought NeXT, I returned to Apple, and the technology we developed at NeXT is at the heart of Apple’s current renaissance. And Laurene and I have a wonderful family together.
https://news.stanford.edu/2005/06/12/youve-got-find-love-jobs-says/

You can search in guru.ludwig that shows usage from newspapers in English and you can find both *we developed* and *we have developed* on both sides of the Atlantic. They mean different things.

[ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/we+have+developed)